# Eclipse: auto kill old version before running it again

Tags: java, eclipse

I am developing a java server in eclipse which don't have any visible output.

I hit ctrl+F11 to start my java server software, and then it starts fine, but if I then edit the source code and start it again eclipse starts a second copy, and I don't want there to be 2 versions of my server running at the same time while I am doing development.

Is there a way to get eclipse to kill the old version, so there always only is one version of my server running.

Comment: In Server view -> Right click on server -> Delete?

Comment: I would really like it to be total automatic. So as soon as I start my newly updated version, the old one will be gone :}

Comment: I assume you're not just able to stop execution from the console?

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10976677/how-to-auto-terminate-instances-of-java-application-in-eclipse